# I want create XML digital signature using nodejs without addrefrence method xpath value to empty

Tags: node.js, xml, xpath

I want to create XML digital signature using nodejs. So I used the xml-crypto

```
npm install xml-crypto
```

In the xml-crypto method called addrefrence contains three parameters. (xpath, transformers, digestalgorithm)
My requirement need to create reference without xpath becomes empty.

```
var sign = new SignedXml()
sig.addReference('', ["http://mytransformation"], 'http://mydigestalgorithm')
```

Got error.
Throw new Error(xpath parse error)

Also give the entire code example for create XML digital signature using nodejs.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask]

Comment: Kindly give solution for this issue...

Comment: The empty string you pass as your first parameter is not a valid XPath expression. You might try the string `'/*'` to identify the root element.

Comment: it gives  <Reference URI="#_0"> but I want <Reference URI="">

Answer (score 0):

The empty '' reference URI is used to de-reference the current document containing the signature. It is commonly used for enveloped signature types. For such type of signatures you may want to use an enveloped-signature tranform (i.e. "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"). This transform will remove the current signature from the reference scope and will apply the following transformations on the original XML content. Usually, when signing an XML, after an enveloped reference transform, a canonicalization algorithm should be applied.
See [XMLDSig](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core1/) for more details.